Selenium IE Driver launches browser window and times out. Suspected Edge 'Tracking Prevention' interference
I have an application that uses Selenium to automate some data collection. As of last week, my IE Driver code has stopped working. I use IE Driver because the devices I interact with all use IE8, IE11, so they do not load correctly within regular MS Edge. Recently, our Edge version was updated, which has had a negative effect on the Selenium code within my application. The IE Driver instance launches the browser, but times out. However, if I manually turn off Edge Tracking Prevention before the 60 second timeout, the IE Driver code continues on as normal.
I have tried testing this code to comply with MS Edge. I cannot access the web page due to incompatible SSL certificates (ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE), as expected. I can bypass this by manually turning on IE Mode and refreshing the page (tracking prevention on or off, does not matter), but this is not a solution to my issue.
Is there a way to overcome the effects of MS Edge Tracking Prevention within IE Driver?
Selenium Specs:
Selenium.WebDriver Version 4.24.0
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver Version 4.14.0
Selenium.Support Version 4.24.0
MS Edge Specs:
Microsoft Edge128.0.2739.42 (Official build) (64-bit)
Revisione015505d79c9432c75e2a9131c445776c61af592
Chromium version128.0.6613.85
Operating system Windows 10 Version 22H2 (Build 19045.4780)
JavaScriptV8 12.8.36.6
Here is the relevant code. I have tried running it with and without ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments. I have also tried launching without an initial URL. Launching a basic IE Driver instance results in the same:
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
{
    AttachToEdgeChrome = true,
    EdgeExecutablePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe",
    //ieOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;
    IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
    InitialBrowserUrl = Url,
    IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
    RequireWindowFocus = false,
    //AcceptInsecureCertificates = true,
    //ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
};
ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "--disable-features=msEnhancedTrackingPreventionEnabled --ignore-certificate-errors --allow-running-insecure-content --allow-insecure-localhost";
ieOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Off);
ieOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Client, LogLevel.Off);
ieOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.Off);
ieOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Profiler, LogLevel.Off);
ieOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Server, LogLevel.Off);
var driverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(driverService, ieOptions);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();


I would like to know how you determined that the timeout issue was caused by Edge's 'Tracking Prevention'. I tested the code you provided, but there was no error. If it is convenient, please provide the error message for me. In addition, because I use IE driver, and Edge setting cannot be turned on. I would also like to know how you manually turn off Edge Tracking Prevention (what kind of scenario is it).

Manually Turning off Tracking prevention is the only action I have noticed that immediately continues Selenium. This involves clicking the " i " that precedes the URL and toggling the on/off switch button. I found this when I went to download the certificate. In my mind, disabling Tracking prevention solves the IE Driver "stall" that I am seeing. I cannot figure out how to successfully programmatically disable tracking prevention in the created browser instance, so that when IE Driver navigates, it can do so successfully - even to a local host address.

When searching the edge version 128.0.2739.42 release, Microsoft directly mentions making changes that affect Selenium, but not specific to my issue. The release date for this version is the last day my code successfully ran.
"Fixed an issue that caused high CPU usage of renderer processes when running Selenium tests and calling driver.quit() to end the testing session."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-relnote-stable-channel#version-1280273942-august-22-2024

This has been resolved with the most recent update (as of 9/9/24) 128.0.2739.67. All existing code is now completing as it was before this posted issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I read your reply and I understand what you mean. I searched for relevant resources and did some tests, and I can provide you with the following suggestions:

I tried to disable "Tracking prevention" programmatically, and it worked when I used the "EdgeOptions" class in selenium Edge. But I didn't find any way to achieve this in IEDriver. Maybe it's because the option settings of IEDriver are different from those of EdgeDriver, and "Tracking prevention" cannot be disabled directly in IEDriver through command line parameters.

But when I deployed the "Tracking prevention" policy in Edge (TrackingPreventionOff (0) = Off (no tracking prevention)), this effect can also be successfully applied to IEDriver, that is, "Tracking prevention" can be successfully turned off when running selenium IE Driver. You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#trackingprevention

If you are sure that this issue is caused by the update of Edge to version 128, you can also roll back Edge to the previous version. You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-rollback to roll back the version of Edge. Of course. You can also press "Shift+Alt+I" in Edge to submit feedback to report this issue. The developers  may see your feedback and fix this issue in future versions.



I will look into 2 & 3 and get back to you.

Update 128.0.2739.67 has resolved this issue.
